# Ajuda com animação conforme scroll com javascript

Tags: javascript, rolamento, array, helper

Tenho uma imagem vetorial

```
<img src="images/first-page/vectors/waves-723178.svg" alt="Imagem vetorial decorativa" class="vector-wave">
```

e a  mesma está posicionada a esquerda da tela

```
.vector-wave {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-500px, 420px);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

exibindo então apenas parte da imagem.

A questão é: quando eu "scrollar" a minha página, esta imagem deverá ir para a direita, até certo ponto;

De forma que se "scrollo" para baixo a imagem vai para a direita, caso contraio, "scrollo" para cima a imagem retornar a esquerda.

Exemplo:[Repare na imagem que que está a esquerda desta url](http://sevenlink.com.br/site/)

PS: Vi um plug in chamado Super scroll orama, mas achei complicado de usar, caso alguém saiba como usa-lo me ajudaria muito também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisas saber 3 coisas:

- altura do scroll
- largura da tela
- o scroll específico a cada momento

Sabendo a altura do scroll e a largura da tela sabes a proporção que a imagem se deve mexer para cada tamanho de scroll. Para saber as dimensões podes usar o [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Para saber o scroll no momento tens de adicionar um oscultador de eventos para o `scroll`.

Um exemplo simples seria assim:

```
var dimensoes = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
var altura = dimensoes.height;
var largura = dimensoes.width;
var imagem = document.querySelector('img');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = window.scrollY;
    var posImagem = scroll * largura / altura;
    imagem.style.left = posImagem + 'px';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2bu5edu/