# Recuperar id conforme o scroll do javascript

Tags: javascript

Fala pessoal,
Beleza?

Estou com um probleminha aqui e preciso do help de vocês hehehehe.

Tenho a seguinte situação

```
<section id="section">    
//TODO CODE
</section>
```

E estou com uma duvida de coletar o id da section com o js quando eu passo com o scroll, atualmente faço algo como `evt.path[1].window.scrollY > 1700` para que eu consiga dar ação em uma function, mas eu necessito que quando eu passe com o scroll por cima do elemento eu consiga coletar aquele id, ou que me faça me notificar algo que estou em cima daquele elemento.

Agradeço a atenção,
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Será algo parecido com https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68612/129?

Comment: Opa Sergio, não era bem isso, mas me deu outra ideia. Valeuuu, de qualquer forma agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solução:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', evt => {
                   evt.path[1].window.scrollY > x.target.getBoundingClientRect().top ? variavel : null
                });
```